# VLC configuration file on Ubuntu 18.10 when installed with snap

Tags: configuration, vlc, 18.10

I have installed `vlc` with `snap` on Ubuntu 18.10, and the result of my search on the internet says that the configuration file for `vlc` should be located in `~/.config/vlc`, but for me, there's no such directory on my system, so I was wondering where can I find the configuration file(s) for `vlc` in case I want to have a backup?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

`/snap/vlc/current/bin/vlc-snap-wrapper.sh` seems to be passing the argument `--config=$SNAP_USER_COMMON/vlcrc` when invoking VLC.

Looking on the snapcraft website https://snapcraft.io/docs/environment-variables#SNAP_USER_COMMON it looks like the typical value for `$SNAP_USER_COMMON` is `$HOME/snap/<snap package name>/common`

Putting this all together the path to your vlc config should be `$HOME/snap/vlc/common/vlcrc`. It can confirm this is the location on my system (Ubuntu 18.04)